# Two get's keep changing each other

Tags: php, html, get

I'm trying to update a database from two id's. One arrives with an other page. And one gets send by an element on the page. The problem is that both are send by GET so they keep changing each other. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
<?php
$id1 = $_REQUEST["id"];
echo $id1;
if($_GET["Action"] == "Wijzig")  
{  
    include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
    $strSQL = "UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='".$_GET["id"]."'";  
    $strSQL .="WHERE unit_id = '".$id1."' ";  
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);  
}

\\Action on current page
    <li><a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('Heeft u de goede geselecteerd?')==true){window.location='<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>?Action=Wijzig&id=<?=$row["id"];?>';}"><?php echo $row['phonenr'];?></a></li>
\\Action on previous page
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('test.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=5000, height=5000'); return false;" ><img src="images/arrowUpDown.png"/></a>
```

Comment: You should not use GET parameters to trigger an UPDATE, since the browser may resubmit the page when the user presses backwards button.

Comment: In the above Code You Only Sending `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` where is `id1`..??

Comment: It is $row['id'] from two pages, which is sent

Comment: So what should i use then? Do you have any alternative for the GET?. id1 is send in the last code at the bottom.

Comment: As a side note, you should try using PDO instead of native mysql_* functions! If not, please tell me you escape your GET data!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid the GET and make it a POST:

- put a hidden form on the page named actionform containing hidden type form fields "Action" and "id".
- `<li><a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Heeft u de goede geselecteerd?')){document.forms.actionform.elements['id'].value='<?php echo $row['id'];?>';} return false;"><?php echo $row['phonenr'];?></a></li>`

This should put the id in the form, submit the form, and return false to indicate that the default action of the a is not to be executed.

Regarding your duplication problem, explain it better, but maybe the return false helps.

Comment: I corrected myself, and used an onclick handler instead which returns false.

Comment: Allright i used this and it seems to work. But i still have my duplication problem. I'll try to explain it. So i got one id which arrives from a previous page which i store in a variable. Then using this script i select another id. The purpose of this is too update an table with those 2 id's in it. But whenever i store the second value in an variable the first one disapears.